# What's the name of the pattern where you draw a rectangle to select items?

Tags: design-patterns, selection, multi-selection

I'm implementing a UI where you can draw a box by clicking and dragging your mouse to select multiple items. Like selecting multiple files/folders:

[image: Screenshot]

Does this pattern have a name?

Comment: Drag-select, click-and-drag https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/dragsele.htm

Comment: **This is NOT off topic.** The [Help center](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) clearly states that `Questions about HCI` are on topic. This is a question about a particular pattern found in human-computer interfaces.

Comment: This is the default behavior for copying elements of the UI. Why would someone need another name for copying?

Comment: @MadalinaTaina Using this select tool doesn't copy them... it only selects them. Once they are selected, the user can work with them all at once. Perhaps they will copy them, perhaps they will delete them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this referred to as:

- Drag to select
- Rectangle select
- Click and drag (I don't recommend using this name, as it's easily confused with dragging individual files)

Comment: "Rectangle (or rectangular) select" is the term I see most frequently.

Answer (score 2):

In Axure this feature is named "select contained". 
In my opinion, you could name this: "select contained items" or "Drag to select contained items".

Answer (score 2):

Marquee select  or area select.

Answer (score 1):

This is also referred to as "rubberband selection", as a [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=rubber%20band%20selection) reveals. Incidentally, as you mention that you're developing a UI, the Qt UI framework has the [`QRubberBand`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrubberband.html#details) class that can be used to implement this type of selection.